# How to implement encapsulation for this simple scenario?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have a js lib file whose variable I don't want to be directly available to other files. Example:

My first file called lib.js is as follows :

lib.js

```
var foo = 90;

function printFoo(){
    console.log(foo)
}
```

In the second file below which calls lib.js, I want printFoo() work fine but I also want direct access to variable foo from lib.js being prevented. How can I do that?

```
<script src="lib.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log(foo);// I don't want foo of lib.js being accessible here

  printFoo();// but i want this line to display the value of foo from lib.js
</script>
```

Comment: Revealing function pattern? A simple IIFE?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want only accesible foo in lib.js
so

```
function printFoo(){
var foo = 90;
return function(){
    console.log(foo)
}
}
```

and the html will be

```
<script src="lib.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log(foo);// here foo is undefined

  var Foo = printFoo();
Foo()// here console .logo of foo 90
// but i want this line to display the value of foo from lib.js
</script>
```

Now foo is under foo() scope, so the way to access is in the encapsulation of printFoo function